# Google Maps API v3: Custom road color is also applied to satellite mode roads

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I changed the map to black and white using JSON styles. This works perfectly. However, if you switch to satellite mode and activate the labels (new checkbox) there because you want to read street and city names, the streets are white there too, which is annoying.
Is it possible to prevent the styles from being applied in satellite mode as well, or to set a separate transparent color there?

```
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: 1) When asking a question, you are supposed to include a [mcve] along with your attempts at solving the issue 2) It doesn't sound from your question like you have tried anything 3) the `Map` class has a `getMapTypeId` method, a `setOptions` method and a `maptypeid_changed` event which all together should allow you to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution. Thanks to [@MrUpsidown's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74401854/google-maps-api-v3-custom-road-color-is-also-applied-to-satellite-mode-roads#comment131347284_74401854).

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "maptypeid_changed", function() {
    var newMapType = map.getMapTypeId();
    if(newMapType == google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP) 
      map.setOptions({styles: styles});
    else
      map.setOptions({styles: null});
});
```